# Stop tessseract recognize in Android

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two

I use Tess_two library and need to interrupt recognizing(method getUTF8Text) if it goes too long. How can i do it. Method stop() dosen't work((

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getHOCRText` instead of `getUTF8Text` if you want to use stop().